# function returns all properties but must only return the one that was called

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write something so that I can encapsulate all my functions into one place nice and neatly and call them by there property name, but what's happening is that whenever I call one property it returns then all.

How do I make `main('test').f3;`  only log 'f3test' and still maintain my concept.

```
var main = function (t) {

    var f1 = function () { console.log('f1' + ' ' + t); };
    var f2 = function () { console.log('f2' + ' ' + t); };
    var f3 = function () { console.log('f3' + ' ' + t); };
    var f4 = function () { console.log('f4' + ' ' + t); };
    var f5 = function () { console.log('f5' + ' ' + t); };
    var f6 = function () { console.log('f6' + ' ' + t); };
    var f7 = function () { console.log('f7' + ' ' + t); };
    var f8 = function () { console.log('f8' + ' ' + t); };


    return {
        f1: f1(),
        f2: f2(),
        f3: f3(),
        f4: f4(),
        f5: f5(),
        f6: f6(),
        f7: f7(),
        f8: f8(),
    }


}




//this
    main('test').f3; 
//will console.log
//f1test
//f2test
//f3test
//f4test
//f5test
//f6test
//f7test
//f8test
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U75hj/1/ just in case you wanted to test the solutions in the answers sectionn :-).

Comment: why does jsfiddle return it twice?  or is that just jsfiddles issue?

Comment: When you hit run it runs the code only once. But it also runs the code on the page load as well. I think that's the reason you are seeing it twice. But every subsequent time you hit run it runs only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you code a little:

```
return {
    f1: f1,
    f2: f2,
    f3: f3,
    f4: f4,
    f5: f5,
    f6: f6,
    f7: f7,
    f8: f8 // <-- don't put last comma here
}
```

`()` executes the function immediately and you need to provide a reference. Then you call it like:

```
main('test').f3(); // f3 test
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
return {
    f1: f1(),
    f2: f2(),
    f3: f3(),
    f4: f4(),
    f5: f5(),
    f6: f6(),
    f7: f7(),
    f8: f8(),
}
```

to

```
return {
    f1: f1,
    f2: f2,
    f3: f3,
    f4: f4,
    f5: f5,
    f6: f6,
    f7: f7,
    f8: f8,
}
```

and

```
main('test').f3;
```

to

```
main('test').f3();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the function variable instead of function result like:

```
return {
        f1: f1,
        f2: f2,
        f3: f3,
        f4: f4,
        f5: f5,
        f6: f6,
        f7: f7,
        f8: f8,
}
```

And call it like

```
main('test').f3();
```